# How to save the subView that has been added with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm working in a book app, and I want to use a page marker to help the user remember where he stopped reading. So I have added a bar button with an image ("mark.png"). A mark view will be added to the chapter view when it is tapped, and if it is been tapped again the mark will be removed from the `superView`. I'm using this code:

```
- (void)showMark {
    if (![markView superView]) {
       [chapterOne addSubView:markView];
    }
    else {
       [markView removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

It is working fine but ever time I exit the app and rerun again the mark view is gone, so how can I keep it?
I found some forums talking about the `NSUserDefaults` to save actions but I really don't know how to use it with my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the great help I will try all you suggestions .

Answer (score 3):

You can't use NSUserDefaults to save entire views, but you can save the parmeters that would help determine where the bookmark should be set.

For example if you are basing the book mark by a page number you could save the page to the NSUserDefaults when the user leaves the view controller.

**Example:**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:23 forKey:@"bookMarkPage"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When the user comes back the the view controller you can check if there is a bookmark:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bookMarkPage"] != nil) {
    int pageNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bookMarkPage"];
    [self setBookmarkForPage:pageNumber];
}
```

Possible bookmark construction method:

```
- (void) setBookmarkForPage:(Int)pageNumber {
    // run through the logic of placing the bookmark on the correct page
}
```

You can use whatever parameters you need to determine where to place the book mark. When a user originally places the bookmark what parameters you use to figure out where to place the bookmark? Try to use the same logic for when a user first places the bookmark.

Comment: Actually I'm not using page number but I will try to adjust your code a little hopefully I can make it works. Thanks.

Comment: woz is right about making a method.  That way you can pass in the bookmark parameters.

Comment: Just updated with an example method.  It is hard to know exactly what should be in the "setBookmarkForPage:" method without knowing exactly how you need to construct it.

Comment: Can i use tag instead of page number?

Comment: Yes.  I'm assuming you are talking about a tag for a UI widget, like a UIButton, UIView, etc.  If this is the case then Yes you can.  A tag is of type NSInteger.  You can store a NSInteger in NSUserDefaults by using the convenience method "setInteger".  Here is an example:   

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:<#(NSInteger)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>];

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you want to save, but you can just about any kind of data with `NSUserDefaults`, like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:123 forKey:@"CurrentPageNumber"];
```

When you have set all the values you need, save them:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then when app opens, check to see if the value is set. If it is draw your marker.

```
if ([defaults valueForKey:@"CurrentPageNumber"] != nil) {
    int pageNumber = [defaults valueForKey:@"CurrentPageNumber"]

    if (pageNumber == 1) {
        [chapterOne addSubView:markView];
    }
    else {
        [markView removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to save the subView that has been added to the view.

Comment: I would really advise writing a method, something like `addPageMarkerView`, that you can call if the user default value is set.

Comment: Can you please give a sample code of that ? It is my first app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer with a rough version. I'm not exactly sure how the rest of your code works, so I can't say for sure how you're tracking chapters and page numbers in your views.

Comment: Do I really need to use page numbers to do this ?

Comment: If you want to mark the exact page the user stopped on, then yes, you have to save the page numbers. I agree with @KevinM on using something like `-(void)setBookmarkForPage:(int)pageNumber`.

Comment: You can use whatever parameters you need to determine where to place the book mark.  When a user originally places the bookmark what parameters you use to figure out where to place the bookmark?  Try to use the same logic for when a user first places the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers state great ways to work around the issue. Just to clarify, UIView or any of the derivatives are not supported for `NSUserDefaults`. `NSUserDefaults` allows just primitive object types (`NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, and NSDictionary`). There might be one or two I missed. But `UIView` or `UIViewController` object types can't be saved in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: But I saw that in a similar book apps , so how do you think they did it? Thanks.

Comment: As the other answers stated, my guess is that the subview is linked by page number or some other arbitrary marker unique to the page. Word count? Other markers in the text of the book? The "right" solution is outside the scope of your question. You may want to mark this one as answered and re-ask a new one more specific to what you learned here. Hope that helps.